# How to append multiple data-attrribute keyword matches from separate html doc to a list

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to make a simple script that loads list items from another document into a div based on data-attribute keyword matches.

I have the following html in a separate doc (relateds.html):

```
<ul id="bigstories">
    <li data-related="ladot transit wayfinding airports" class="related"><a href="/work/work_wayfinding_sfo.html">Wayfinding at San Fransisco International Airport</a></li>
    <li data-related="transit primo sanantonio" class="related"><a href="/work/work_primo.html">The Primo Brand for San Antonio</a></li>
    <li data-related="transit ladot" class="related"><a href="/work/work_ladot.html">Keeping LA on the Move</a></li>
    <li data-related="transit seattle metro" class="related"><a href="/work/work_wayfinding_sfo.html">King County’s BRT plan begins with RapidRide</a></li>

    <li data-related="parking ladot" class="related"><a href="/work/work_wayfinding_sfo.html">LA Express Park Streamlines Parking in Downtown LA</a></li>
</ul>
```

The script below is meant to iterate over the list above, and if it finds any keywords in the data-related attribute that match any of those in the same attribute of the target div, grabs that li and appends it to the target ul. It also should stop looking once the max of three matches is found.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    FetchRelatedData(3);
});

    function FetchRelatedData(max) {

        //Fetch the relateds.html
        $.get("relateds.html", function (data) {

            //Find all list items with a related regarding attribute.
            var relateds = $(data).find("[data-related*='" + $("#relatedStories").data("related") + "']");
            console.log(relateds);


            $.each(relateds, function (i, a) {
                //append each related item to the .relatedStories section.
               $("#relatedStories").append("<li>" + $(a).html() + "</li>");
            });

            if (i >= max) { return false; }


        }, "html");
}
```

This kind of works, but seemingly only with one keyword, or with multiple keywords in one list item. When multiple keywords match data-related for more than one list item (e.g., data-regarding="primo airports", the list turns up empty. Also looks like I'm failing to define i here and the maximum portion isn't working.

If it's not obvious by now, I'm a total JQuery scrub. This was an attempt at adapting a similar script a developer put together for me with a previous project. I'm amazed it's working even this well, frankly.

Is there a way to achieve this with multiple matches across list items? And where did I go wrong defining i?

Half-working example at http://s.ilium.com/work/related-test.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.  It supports any number of 'related' keywords on #relatedStories, and is looking for those keywords to be comma delimited.  I also switched from window.load to document.ready, as it is a little faster in this case.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    FetchRelatedData(3);
})

function FetchRelatedData(max) {

    //Fetch the relateds.html
    $.get("relateds.html", function (data) {
        //get the keywords to match
        var keysToMatch = $('#relatedStories').attr('related').split(',');

        //set up counter
        var counter = 0;

        //loop through the list items
        $(data).find('li').each(function(index, elem) {
            // return if counter is >= max
            if (counter >= max) {
                return;
            }
            // get the element's keywords
            var elemKeys = $(elem).attr('data-related');

            // loop through keysToMatch
            var match = false;
            $.each(keysToMatch, function(index, key) {
                // if the key matches any of the element's keywords, set match to true
                if (elemKeys.match(key) !== null) {
                    match = true;
                }
            });
            // if theres a match, append the element's contents
            // to the page and increment the counter
            if (match === true) {
                $("#relatedStories").append("<li>" + $(elem).html() + "</li>");
                counter++;
            }
        })
    }, "html");
```

}

Comment: At first this threw a TypeError: `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$('#relatedStories').attr('related').split')`

Comment: looking at your original code, I see you used .data() where I used .attr(), switching this might fix it, depending on how the data you are attaching to the #relatedStories with .data() is formatted

Comment: but then I changed `.attr('related')` to `.attr('data-related')` and it started pulling the headlines. Only problem is it still wasn't handling multiple keywords, it seems... when I plug in `ladot primo`, which should match the first two list items, the list turns up empty, similar to the original problem.